# Get Data from firebase for swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I have below code to get data from my firebase database

```
db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("starting name display")
            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                let documentUserId = document.get("uid") as?String
                let temp = document.data()["displayName"]
                print(temp)
            }
          }
        }
```

The print statement displays as optional("test name")
Why am i keep getting optional in my string. Same displays on the screen as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `un-wrap` because it's an `Optional`. Means it could have a value or it could not have a value. So this is one method to handle it:

```swift
let temp = document.data()["displayName"] ?? ""
print(temp)
```

You could also use `if let` or `guard let` statements if you need to handle the cases where the value is actually empty.

Note: Take a look at the [basics of swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). There is a separate section for `Optionals`.